# drawing two lines on a facerecognition live video capture

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2012

i'm using opencv with c++ for a face recognition application, the face recognition part works just fine until i wanted to add two lines on the video capture to split it on 3 parts, this is my code i'm using opencv 2.4.11 and visual studio 2012:i wrote this part to insert lines in an image but for a video i dont get anything .

```
Mat image;
image = imread("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pfedocs\\ggg_opt.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);  

    line(image,Point(25,0),Point(25,500),Scalar(0,255,0),3,2,0);
line(image,Point(190,0),Point(190,500),Scalar(0,255,0),3,2,0);
line(image,Point(355,0),Point(355,500),Scalar(0,255,0),3,2,0);
```

can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Please see [ask], and provide a [mcve]... Stress on **Minimal**.

Comment: the problem i'am having is with drawing the line all along with the face detection algorithm ,the line won't show in the frame

Comment: So the real question is: _"How can I draw two lines on a video?"_

Comment: yess tha'ts is my question ,i already succeeded drawing lines on an image in a facedetection through images.

Comment: Then please remove all code and stuff **unrelated** to your actual question. See how to do a [mcve]

Comment: i enclosed the lines of code i used to insert lines in an images above which doesnt work for a video (webcam live capture)